# Modeling and validating a form with multiple submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to figure out the proper way to model and validate a form with multiple form tags and multiple submit buttons using ASP.Net Core 2. What I have is a form where a user can either enter their username and password and sign in OR enter their first name, last name and cell number and sign up. Here is my model:

```
public class Landing
{
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CellNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my relevant razor view code:

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.Landing

<form method="post">
    <div>
        <input asp-for="Username" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input asp-for="Password" type="password" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
    </div>
</form>

<form method="post">
    <div>
        <input asp-for="FirstName" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input asp-for="LastName" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input asp-for="CellNumber" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Now the problem I run into is with my validation. Because all my fields are marked with the `[Required]` attribute, when I submit the form using either submit button, it's validating all 5 fields. What I want to do is validate `UserName` and `Password` only, IF the first submit button is pushed OR validate `FirstName`, `LastName` and `CellNumber` only, IF the second submit button is pushed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Separate view models will solve the problem, no ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would break my models into two class and then use a [`ViewModel`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc) instead:

```
public class SignIn
{
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class SignUp
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CellNumber { get; set; }
}

public class LandingViewModel
{
    public SignIn SignIn { get; set; }
    public SignUp SignUp { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.LandingViewModel
SignIn.Username, SignIn.Password, SignUp.FirstName,...
```

Comment: Just so you know, the modelbinder will only new up classes if there's at least one property value posted. In other words, if you submit none of the properties for `SignUp`, then that will be null. If you design your form properly, this can be used to determine which form the user submitted without separate buttons.