# Stored procedure returns two tables how to move data from model to view

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, stored-procedures, model-view-controller

I have a stored procedure that returns two tables this two tables I store them in two lists example: `List<SpObject1> ob1 and List<SpObject2> ob2`.

What is the best way to return this data from model to view ? I can create another class(tuple) that can store 2 lists and return them to controller but will this be problem to display on view like this and is it good solution ?

Comment: You can use a [ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc) in this scenarios, an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/50509915/2946329

Comment: ViewModel  is the best way to handle this in MVC.

Comment: thank you for answers I will try this.

Comment: alternatively you can also use `ViewBag`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always try and use ViewModels when returning any data to a view.

[Modeling and validating a form with multiple submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50509795/modeling-and-validating-a-form-with-multiple-submit/50509915#50509915)

is a good example.

In your controller you will just pass your Lists to that view model and then use the viewModel as a @model.