# Issue with using two models in the view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I am trying to use two models in my view, but I am get an error saying that only one model can be used. I get the purpose of why only one model can be used but are there any workarounds so I could use two models in my view. I have listed the code below.

Controller:

```
/* Parts Method */
public ActionResult Parts()
{
    return View(db.Part.ToList());
}
```

View:

@model Inventory_System.Models.Transaction
   @model IQueryable

The first model is for connecting to the view model and the second is connecting to a database list from the controller to be displayed. How could I use both of these models in the same view?

Comment: You need to make a _ViewModel_ that contains both things as properties.  You can only use one Model in a view

Comment: You need to use a a `ViewModel` as @maccettura already mentioned. Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/50509915/2946329

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a composite model with two properties.

**View Model**

```
public class CompositeModel
{
  public Transaction  Transaction {get;set}
  public List<Part> ListOfParts {get;set}   
}
```

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Parts()
{
   CompositeModel model = new CompositeModel
   {
     Transaction = new Transaction();
     ListOfParts = db.Part.ToList();
   };
   return View(model);
}
```

**View**

```
@model /*Name Space*/.CompositeModel;
```

I think that is good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a ViewModel that contains your two models

```
public class ViewModel()
{
    public Inventory_System.Models.Transaction Transaction {get;set;}
    public IQueryable<Inventory_System.Models.Part> Part {get;set;}

}
```